# (beginner c GUI program) GTK+ and C program is having problems with showing the icon

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, icons

I am following the tutorial shown below from here:http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/firstprograms/

My problem is the icon does not show. My operating system is Ubuntu. I have tried a couple of different icons with a couple of different sizes and file types and none of them work. One is a .png at 25 pixels wide and 19 pixels height and another is a .jpg at 185 pixels wide and 210 pixels height. I changed the file referenced in the line that controls this here (which did nothing):
   `gtk_window_set_icon(GTK_WINDOW(window), create_pixbuf("web.png"));`

I even tried changing settings in the configuration editor for gnome by enabling the option for menus to have icons.

I googled around some and did not find anything that helped, so I thought I would ask the excellent coders at stackoverflow. ^_*

Thanks for reading.

Your Pal,

user2085446

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GdkPixbuf *create_pixbuf(const gchar * filename)
{
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GError *error = NULL;
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(filename, &error);
    if(!pixbuf) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error->message);
       g_error_free(error);
    }

  return pixbuf;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
   GtkWidget *window;

   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "icon");
   gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 230, 150);
   gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
   gtk_window_set_icon(GTK_WINDOW(window), create_pixbuf("web.png"));
   gtk_widget_show(window);

   g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   gtk_main();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using the fully-qualified path to the web.png file.

Comment: the image is in the same directory as the program... so the full-path is already there with this in mind. Thanks though. It could of been the problem indeed sir.

Comment: Try using ./web.png or actually putting the full path in your code that and check the permissions on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every window manager theme shows icons in the title bar. I believe Ubuntu's default one doesn't. (The `gtk_window_set_icon` function is just a hint, the window manager is free to ignore it.) From the looks of @syler's screenshot, they are not using the default Ubuntu theme, so the icon shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I have run this program with a png file at 48x48 pixels, the program works well.
My operating system is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. 
besides the png file is the same dir as program, or set the absolute directory

[image: the icon is on the top left]